# print the first word of the line twice, then the rest of the line

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following file:

#### F1

---

> This is the first line.
>
> And the second line.

---

I want the output to be:

> This This This is the first line.
>
> And And And the second line.

---

I run the following command:

> sed -re 's/([^ ]+).*/\1 \1/' F1

It does print twice the first word of the line like this:

> This This
>
> And And

but I don't know how to print the whole line afterwords.

> This This **This is the first line.**
>
> And And **And the second line**.

I need it as a 'sed' command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
sed -re 's/([^ ]+)(.*)/\1 \1 \1\2/' F1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `awk` for this (and it should make it a bit more readable):

```
awk '{print $1, $1, $0}' F1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -re 's/([^ ]+).*/\1 \1 \0/' F1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Sed with & command

```
sed -re 's/([^ ]+)/& \1 \1/' F1
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy with pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
while read -r first rest; do
    printf '%s %s %s %s\n' "$first" "$first" "$first" "$rest"
done < F1
```